# In django I have created "tool" app, When I try to import tool to other file I got error "No module named 'tool' "

Tags: python, django, django-models

[please check the following image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kyf5.png)

```
from tool.models import loginauth
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tool'
```

Comment: show models.py from tool app

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you have created app inside the internal directory of project. Which shouldn't be soo. If you still want to go with the same structure as present please replace this line with the one causing error.

```
from techticket.tool.models import loginauth
```

Please comment here If the issue still persist.

Comment: The issue is still persist